# VMware snapshost issue

Tags: windows, macos, mac, vmware-fusion

I am using VMware Fusion 2.0 on a Macbook Pro. I have allocated 20GB to a windows partition within VMware, and now wish to expand that. When I go to the settings for the hard drive it tells me: "These settings cannot be changed while the virtual machine has a snapshot. To make changes, first delete all snapshots." When I go to the snapshots settings nothing appears there besides the current state thumbnail.
Is there a way to remove these "invicible" snapshots??

Comment: Is this VM Suspended or Off?

Answer (score 1):

Have you got auto-protect on?

In the window showing snapshots there is a check box at bottom left that toggles showing the protection snapshots

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem while I was trying to expand my virtual machine as well. The virtual machine was fully powered down and there were no visible snapshots, but it still said I had one.

My solution was to make a new snapshot and delete it. Hopefully this will fix your problem as well.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and your solution worked very well for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use VMWare Converter to convert this VM to a new VM. All snapshots will be deleted as part of the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate using the terminal to the directory containing your VM:

$ ls -lha

you should see some "name-SnapshotX" (where X denotes how many times you've taken a snapshot) files.

You CAN delete these, but not recommended.

As far as resizing your HDD. VMware Converter (Windows only) is the best way of doing this due to the automated partition adjustment. As if you do it manually (by adding more through Fusion HDD dialog), you'll just have a large drive, with a lot of empty space, which your Windows will not recognise, and then you'll have to muck around with partition resizing internally.

Hope that helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I had a an issue with a VM where I wanted to change the disk mode, however I had already taken a snapshot of it.

it sort of gave me the same error message as yours when I tried to delete it.

I finally got rid of the snapshot by creating another snapshot and deleting them all.